# Pandas dataframe groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to pandas and I'm a bit confused about groupby.  If I have a dataframe like:

[image: pic1]

Then: `df.groupby(['A']).count()` returns something like (not exactly but close):
[image]

My question is what happens when you group by more than 1 column? like:

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).count()
```

does it regroup columns A,B and C then calculates the counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` counts the number of non-null values.  In a `groupby` context, it counts the number of non-null values in each group.  When you `groupby` multiple columns at once, `groupby` creates a group for each unique combination.  So... `df.groupby(['A','B','C']).count()` counts the number of non-null values for each column for each unique combination of values in `['A', 'B', 'C']`

Consider the sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz'),
        B=list('111122221111222211112222'),
        C=list('abababababababababababab'),
        D=list(range(23)) + [np.nan]
    ))
```

Then

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).count()

       D
A B C   
x 1 a  2
    b  2
  2 a  2
    b  2
y 1 a  2
    b  2
  2 a  2
    b  2
z 1 a  2
    b  2
  2 a  2
    b  1
```